# How Do I Tell If VBA ActiveX is disabled on Windows 10?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, activex

I have written an Excel VBA for a UserForm that has a button that calls CommonDialog.ShowColor.

On my developer system there are no issues, on our networked systems ActiveX is disabled due to security concerns.

I can live with the error warnings on initial loading of the Excel Workbook, what I want to avoid is having the VBA Editor come up when a user clicks the button to show the Color Dialog.

I've tried On Error Goto within the button_click event but that does not work.

Is there a way to test, from within VBA, if ActiveX is disabled and then disable the button?

Thanks

Comment: To test if ActiveX is disabled, you're going to have to look at the Windows registry. You have to determine which registry settings has your organization changed to disable it. Take a look at [this information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users) and [this information](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fdcc/2011/11/03/enabling-initialize-and-script-activex-controls-not-marked-as-safe-in-any-zone-can-get-you-hurt-bad/). Determine where the setting is and then you can set up a function in VBA to read it.

Comment: *"I've tried On Error Goto within the button_click event but that does not work."* Please note that we cannot say anything if you don't show your code or a [mcve]. Use the [edit] button to improve your question.

Comment: The network system is locked down, and I can't get access to the registry, even to read it.

I will have to rewrite to avoid using the ActiveX control. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your system administrator is applying group policy:

```vb
Private Sub AX_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim WS As Object, RegistryKey As String, RegistryKeyValue As String
    Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    RegistryKey = _
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\Common\Security\DisableAllActiveX"
    If RegistryKey = "" Then Exit Sub
    If WS.RegRead(RegistryKey) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Disabled"
    Else
        MsgBox "Enabled "
    End If
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Key does not exist."
End Sub
```

Or change the registry key if he uses a different method, like: `trusted files` or `trusted locations`.